# Multiply two 4x4 Matrices

Tags: c, matrix, openmp

```
  fn_mat4 fn_multMat4(fn_mat4 a,fn_mat4 b)
  {

  fn_mat4 ret;

  for (j = 0;j < 4;j++)
  {

  #pragma omp simd
  for (i = 0;i < 4;i++)
     ret.m[i+j*4]= a.m[j*4]*b.m[i] + a.m[j*4 + 1]*b.m[i+4] + a.m[j*4 + 2]*b.m[i+8] + a.m[j*4 + 3]*b.m[i+12];

  }
  return ret;
  }
```

If anybody knows how to reduce this to one loop instead of nested loops it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posing compilable code is courteous and makes for a better review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anybody knows how to reduce this to one loop instead of nested loops it would be greatly appreciated.

2 Alternatives:  Unclear if this make for higher performance code for OP.

```
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    unsigned j4 = j * 4;
    ret.m[j4 + 0] = a.m[j4]*b.m[0] + a.m[j4 + 1]*b.m[0 + 4] + a.m[j4 + 2]*b.m[0 + 8] + a.m[j4 + 3]*b.m[0 + 12];
    ret.m[j4 + 1] = a.m[j4]*b.m[1] + a.m[j4 + 1]*b.m[1 + 4] + a.m[j4 + 2]*b.m[1 + 8] + a.m[j4 + 3]*b.m[1 + 12];
    ret.m[j4 + 2] = a.m[j4]*b.m[2] + a.m[j4 + 1]*b.m[2 + 4] + a.m[j4 + 2]*b.m[2 + 8] + a.m[j4 + 3]*b.m[2 + 12];
    ret.m[j4 + 3] = a.m[j4]*b.m[3] + a.m[j4 + 1]*b.m[3 + 4] + a.m[j4 + 2]*b.m[3 + 8] + a.m[j4 + 3]*b.m[3 + 12];
  }
```

And

```
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    unsigned i = j % 4;
    unsigned j4 = j & 12;  // j4 = j / 4 * 4;
    ret.m[j] = 
          a.m[j4 + 0]*b.m[i + 0] + a.m[j4 + 1]*b.m[i + 4]
        + a.m[j4 + 2]*b.m[i + 8] + a.m[j4 + 3]*b.m[i + 12];
  }
```